# cmd /C "MyBatch.bat Param1 Param2 Param3" works under WinXP but fails under Win7

Tags: windows-7, path, cmd, windows-xp, cd

This command is in the middle of a large batch file that has worked problem-free for more than 5 years under Windows XP, but when run under Windows 7(32bit) it reports "MyBatch.bat is not recognised as an internal/external command, operable program or batch file".

If I edit the main batch file to precede the line with 'cd' or 'dir' it shows the directory where MyBatch.bat exists, but cmd can't find it.

The only way I've found to make the call work is to precede the line with 'set path=%path%;%cd%', but this only works because the location of MyBatch.bat is now in the path. This is an impractical solution for the rest of the main batch file. I can't use 'call MyBatch.bat ...' instead as in other places cmd /C is used to call .exe files.

On my system 'cmd' is set to Administrator mode in the registry and command extensions are enabled (Administrator mode in necessary for some of the processing the main batch file does). I have also tried setting cmd to WINXPSP3 compatibility mode too, but it made no difference.

It is as if the Win7 version of cmd is only using %path% to find things and isn't looking at the directory it is being run from, whereas the WinXP version does. I haven't seen this restriction expressed anywhere.

Have I misunderstood something or missed a step or a registry flag?
Is there a way to make cmd work under Win7 as it did under WinXP?

Comment: You might be right, but you should provide real life data, not `"MyBatch.bat Param1 Param2 Param3"`.

Comment: What is the actual folder being used?  An administrator in Win 7 and Win 8 has less access than an Administrator in Win XP.  Try right clicking the batch file and 'run as admin'.  See if it succeeds.

Comment: @Endoro - Thanks for the reply. I didn't think adding the real params would help as they would only mean something to the batch file processing them, but the full line was:
cmd /C "MkPCBld.bat Release Nowait NoDemo"

Comment: @foxidrive - opening an Admin cmd prompt and navigating to the directory the batch file is in and running:
'MkPCBld.bat Release NoWait NoDemo' works just fine. That's what's so annoying.

Comment: Have you tried `start` command?

Comment: @Falstaff: That would show that it is a permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

If `MyBatch.bat` is in the same directory as the script calling it you can always do this:

```
call "%~dp0MyBatch.bat" ...
```

Comment: Also usable: `.\MyBatch.bat`.

Comment: No. `.` is the working directory, which may be different from the directory in which the scripts reside. Same goes for `%CD%`.

Comment: @Ansgar - Thank you for that. It looks like it might work. By the time call is made we're already 3 layers deep in batch file calls but the outermost is in the same directory as MyBatch. I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: @michaelb958: Thank you. I'd tried that and many other things [B-)] including 'cmd /c "c:\<full path>\MyBatch.bat ..."' which worked but is impractical as the path is different for each dev branch and/or developer's PC.

Comment: Just a thought, the full path to the source files and build utilities is 'C:\Sandboxes\...' as used in WinXP. As we're using Win7 should this be located somewhere else like 'c:\Users\<Username>\Documents\Sandboxes\...'? Might that be the problem?

Comment: If the files are user-specific, they belong in `%USERPROFILE%`. If they are not user-specific, they don't belong in `%USERPROFILE%`. There's no difference between WinXP and Win7 in that respect. Aside from this I don't know even remotely enough about the purpose and structure of your scripts collection to advise you about where to put it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Thanks for the tip about %~dp0. That gave me the clue I needed to fix the problem. I'd set an "AutoRun" directory for cmd.exe in the registry. I hadn't realised that this would take affect whenever cmd was invoked, even in DOS, rather than only when I open a cmd window as intended. I have removed the Autorun entry and it works fine now. Thanks to everybody else for the helpful advice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to examine the `cmd /?` documentation, specifically what happens if the `/d` switch is NOT specified - there are registry entries that control what happens in `CMD` startup and perhaps that are the root-cause of your problem.

I can't verify at present on my machine - I've had no such problems, but the registry entries mentioned are also missing...

Comment: Thank you. I tried the /d option, but it had no effect (in the last 2 days I've tried almost everything). As far as I can tell 'cmd /?' gives the same results on WinXP as it does on Win7. I think it's behaviour is *supposed* to be the same on both. It just doesn't seem to look in the current directory when run on Win7 but does on WinXP. It's frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to AnsgarWiechers for the tip about %~dp0. I added 'cmd /C "Echo %~DP0"' to the batch file to see the directory 'cmd' *thought* it was running from. That gave me the clue I needed to fix the problem.

I'd set an "AutoRun" directory for cmd.exe in the registry. I hadn't realised that this would take affect whenever 'cmd' was invoked, even in a batch file, rather than only when I open a cmd window, as I'd intended.

I have removed the Autorun entry and it works fine now.

Thanks to all of you for the helpful advice.